# SQL: JOIN with nested queries

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to perform this join operation. As I am new to sql I am finding problems understanding the syntax and stuff.

What do you think is wrong with the following query:

```
select top 1 * 
from 
    (select * 
     from dbo.transaction_unrated 
        where transaction_date >= '2012/05/01' 
            and transaction_date < '2012/06/01' 
            and content_provider_code_id in (1)
    )   FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (select * 
     from dbo.transaction_rated 
        where transaction_date >= '2012/05/01' 
            and transaction_date < '2012/06/01' 
            and entity_id in (1) 
            and mapping_entity_id = 1)
    ) 
    ON dbo.transaction_unrated.cst_id = dbo.transaction_rated.unrated_transaction_id
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FULL'.
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Line 16: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 15):

You need to alias your derived tables.

```
select top 1 * 
from 
(
     select * 
     from dbo.transaction_unrated 
        where transaction_date >= '2012/05/01' 
            and transaction_date < '2012/06/01' 
            and content_provider_code_id in (1)
) rsQuery1  
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
     select * 
     from dbo.transaction_rated 
        where transaction_date >= '2012/05/01' 
            and transaction_date < '2012/06/01' 
            and entity_id in (1) 
            and mapping_entity_id = 1)
) rsQuery2 ON rsQuery1.cst_id = rsQuery2.unrated_transaction_id
```

`FULL OUTER JOIN` is also unusual (in my experience).  Are you sure that's what you want?  Typically you will do an `INNER JOIN` which brings back rows that match on your criteria in both tables, or you will let one table be the driver and do a `LEFT` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` which will bring back all the rows in the driving table whether or not there is a match in the other table.  A `FULL OUTER JOIN` will bring back all the rows in both tables regardless of whether they match.